# Delegate/Protocols Passing data from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, extension-methods

Trying to pass data from one view controller MainScreenVC to Another RatesVC with protocol and extension, but that's not working, app crashing everytime . I'm clearly see that problem with code on second VC(because print showing correct data after action on first VC) but not sure where is error.

[StoryBoard and 1st VC Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv28K.png)
[Second VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Jgm.png)

1st View controller

```
import UIKit

protocol transferNameOfCurrency {
    func currencySelected(nameOfCurrency: String)
}

class MainScreenVC: UIViewController {

    var transferCurrencyDelegate: transferNameOfCurrency?
    var nameOfTheCurrency: String?

    @IBAction func updateRates(_ sender: Any) {
        nameOfTheCurrency = "EUR"
        transferCurrencyDelegate?.currencySelected(nameOfCurrency: 
nameOfTheCurrency)
        print(nameOfTheCurrency)

    }
}
```

2nd ViewController

```
import UIKit

class RatesVC: UIViewController {
    var currencySelected: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainScreenVC") as? MainScreenVC
        {
            push.transferCurrencyDelegate = self
        }

         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

extension RatesVC: transferNameOfCurrency {
    func currencySelected(nameOfCurrency: String) {
       currencySelected = nameOfCurrency
       print(currencySelected)
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the crash message? there are several problems with your code..

Comment: In terms of delegate/protocol...this looks fine. FWIW it's better to change the name of `transferNameOfCurrency` to `CurrencyDelegate`.Because that's what it **is**. What it **does** should be part of its function's name. Also change `func currencySelected(nameOfCurrency: String) ` to `func currencyChanged(To: String)`

Comment: Already fixed problem with crash but right now print from first VC showing correct value for nameOfTheCurrency and second one showing nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious problem lies here:

```
if let push = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainScreenVC") as? MainScreenVC {
    push.transferCurrencyDelegate = self
}
```

You have to realize that `instantiateViewController` creates a **new** view controller - it's not the reference to the view controller presented at the screen. In that code you just created a completely new view controller and then set its delegate to `self`, but otherwise nothing else.

Without knowing the context it is really hard to suggest anything - `prepare(for:)` segue might be the place where you want to set the delegate. Anyway, the problem is that you have to obtain a reference to the controller that is presented on the screen, the one that is supposed to be reacting to those events.

Moreover, from the memory management aspect, you should really consider making the `delegate` property a `weak` one to prevent memory leaks.

**EDIT**

So after seeing the minimal working example you provided at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzzv2eg1z2r73aw/New.zip?dl=0), I think I can provide the solution on how to get that string to the `SecondVC`.

Your first view controller with comments:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var newLine: String = "EUR"

    @IBAction func push(_ sender: Any) {
        // here the secondVC does not exist yet, calling delegate.transferWord() here would have no sense
        // performSegue will create that secondVC, but now it does not exist, nor it is set up as the delegate
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController", sender: navigationController)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondVC, segue.identifier == "ViewController" {
            // at this moment secondVC did not load its view yet, trying to access it would cause crash
            // because transferWord tries to set label.text directly, we need to make sure that label
            // is already set (for experiment you can try comment out next line)
            secondVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
            // but here secondVC exist, so lets call transferWord on it
            secondVC.transferWord(word: newLine)
        }
    }
}
```

No need for delegates here, because your `ViewController` is the one pushing the `SecondVC` to the Navigation controller - that means that you can access it directly in `prepare(for:)`, as you can see above.

Now the `SecondVC` is super simple (I omitted unnecessary code):

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func transferWord(word: String) {
        label.text = word
    }
}
```

Storyboards can stay as they are.

Comment: Already tried both prepare(for: ) and that one which i have right now but still receiving nil on second VC

Comment: @Ula what did you try? and what does it mean you are receiving nil on second vc?

Comment: When button will be pressed i want to push value of nameOfTheCurrency to second VC to use this parameter later like a String and at this moment when button pressed i'm receiving print in console from first VC like EUR and print from extension from second VC nil.

Comment: did you even read my answer? you are not really assigning the delegate that you want - you create a new first view controller that does not trigger those methods you are trying to delegate.. you need the reference to the presented first view controller.. this line does not give you that reference, it create a completely new view controller: `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainScreenVC")`

Comment: Also tried this option                                                                            
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let viewController = segue.destination as? MainScreenVC, 
      segue.identifier == "MainScreenVC" {
            viewController.transferCurrencyDelegate = self
         }
       }

Comment: @Ula can you just share the whole project?

Comment: sorry but i can't share whole project here is enough info for analyze

Comment: @Ula there's not enough data to debug, it misses the storyboards - how are the two view controllers related? which one presents which? what presentation does it use? but after all, it is your decision

Comment: just created a small example of the test project added screenshots to first post please take a look.

Comment: @Ula from the screenshot we can tell there's literally 4 classes and a storyboard, what's the reason that you cannot share it?

Comment: That's just example which i created few min ago here is the link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzzv2eg1z2r73aw/New.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @Ula that's better now.. check my updated answer - you don't need a delegate pattern here.

Comment: @Ula sure, an upvote is enough compensation :), and thanks for having the patience to get to the minimal working example :)...